# Detect cell click in cell edit showing reordering control + disclosure control as Safari bookmarks editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to reproduce behaviour of editing bookmarks in iOS Safari like shown here:

[image]

I managed to reproduce the look but I am struggling to detect cell click in editing mode when showing both reordering control and disclosure editing accessory type setting:

```
 cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Basically only the reordering and delete controls seem active, but the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

does not get called ever, how is this achieved then?

Please note I am using UITableViewController, I have implemented also:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // avoid moving "add new" row
    if (indexPath.row > 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.row > 0 ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

Comment: did u set your table view  allowsSelectionDuringEditing to YES ?

Comment: Totally forgot about that, I'll check tomorrow when I am on my Mac and I will try that, if it works I'll accept your answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the  `allowsSelectionDuringEditin`g to `YES`.

**From Documentation:**

> A Boolean value that determines whether users can select cells while
>   the table view is in editing mode.

If the value of this property is YES, users can select rows during editing. The default value is NO. If you want to restrict selection of cells regardless of mode, use allowsSelection.